# PDO not connecting to remote server?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I use mysql_connect('remote_server', 'user', 'pass') it works fine but when I try the following:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;mysql:host=remote_server', 'user', 'pass');
```

It doesn't work. I had mysql-client installed on the web server initially. When trying the PDO connection I was receiving this error:

> Connection Failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

So I installed mysql-server and got the following error instead:

> Connection Failed: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I'm assuming this is because PDO is trying to connect to the local mysql server instead of the remote server. I tried using the local credentials and it connected but this is obviously not what I want. How do I get a connection to the remote server using a PDO connection to a SQL database? Why is it trying to use user@localhost when I specified a remote server in the DSN?

Comment: Your DSN is wrong; remove the second `mysql:` so the string becomes `mysql:dbname=dbname;host=remote_server`.

Comment: `mysql:dbname=dbname;host=remote_server` Why do you add extra `mysql:` to dsn?

Comment: Doh... It seems to be working now. Can't believe I didn't catch that!

Comment: Hi Daniel. Glad you fixed it! To mark it as such, please add a self-answer and click the 'tick' icon (I've done this just now, but if you want to post one, please do, and I will delete mine). This ensures that questions still make sense if they are repurposed via the API, and marks them resolved in the search system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Posted on behalf of the OP:*

Can't believe I didn't catch the error in the DSN. Fixed :)